# I want to show two number picker using dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, numberpicker

I am trying to show two number picker on dialog using java only, The code is working but i am not able to arrange it on equal width.

**here is my code**

```
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);
final NumberPicker aNumberPickerA = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPickerA.setMaxValue(11);
aNumberPickerA.setMinValue(1);
aNumberPickerA.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Tea Cup", "Glass","Plate","Small Plate","Cutlets","Medium","Piece","Katori","Balls","Serving","egg"});

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams qPicerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


numPicerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
qPicerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
relative.setLayoutParams(params);
relative.addView(aNumberPicker,numPicerParams);
relative.addView(aNumberPickerA,qPicerParams);


AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select the number");
alertDialogBuilder.setView(relative);
alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
                Log.e("","New Quantity Value : "+ aNumberPicker.getValue());

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

**I want to align them on equal width.**

**snapshot**
[image: here is my screen and what i am getting]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** on views which are added to **LinearLayout**. You should use **RelativeLayout** in place of **LinearLayout** as parent of **NumberPicker**. Setting the **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** won't work on **LinearLayout**.

Edit:

I would have used a LinearLayout as parent with setting orientation to Horizontal and children weights to '1'. Which would be something like this...

```
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
//
final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);
//
final NumberPicker aNumberPickerA = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPickerA.setMaxValue(11);
aNumberPickerA.setMinValue(1);
aNumberPickerA.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Tea Cup", "Glass","Plate","Small Plate","Cutlets","Medium","Piece","Katori","Balls","Serving","egg"});
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
numPicerParams.weight = 1;
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams qPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
qPicerParams.weight = 1;
//
LL.setLayoutParams(params);
LL.addView(aNumberPicker,numPicerParams);
LL.addView(aNumberPickerA,qPicerParams);
```

I hope this helps.

Good Luck. :)

Comment: I have edited the question actually linearLayout was the name of object of relative layout. Please check once again and guide me.