# I want to show two number picker using one dialog

Tags: java, android

Hi this is exactly what Ive been looking for to add into my app ([I want to show two number picker using dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525915/i-want-to-show-two-number-picker-using-dialog/28023002#28023002)) but I'm getting an error mContext is undefined - how do i fix this? Also is there a way to do this with an xml layout? Thank you in advance (I'm pretty new to android)

Comment: please add some code and the LogCat-Output so we can analyze your error

Comment: mcontext is a defined variable as a application context.you need to define in your code

Comment: `is there a way to do this with an xml layout?` **NO**. You define your contexts in Java code only.

Comment: The code used on the link - I'll adjust it for my own needs just wanted to remove the error first :).  Unfortunately I am new to stackoverflow and am unable to post my code :(

Answer (score 0):

please follow this link...
 https://pandiyanblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/android-number-picker-inside-the-custom-dialog-box/

Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="255dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top|center"
android:background="#50CCCCCC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="   "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expmin"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expmin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/np"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Exp.Min"
        android:textColor="#3276b1"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Exp.Max"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#3276b1"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/np"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/np"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="  OK  "
        android:textColor="#3276b1" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>

 <!--  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:text="  OK  "
    android:textColor="#3276b1" /> -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Your xml violates xml rules. Only one top level element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this :) - unfortunately im getting errors in java (Cannot resolve symbol)

Comment: I'm getting this on quite afew things including
-requestWindowFeature
- setContentView
- length
- setMaxValue
- setMinValue

Comment: Could it be to do with what my main activity extends? (sorry im new to android)

Comment: Could you pls post all the coding snippets what you have implemented for numberpic...